# Return True if no character in String s is a vowel in Python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, for-loop

I've tried looking for answers but none seem to help. I've done:

```
def noVowel(s):
    'return True if string s contains no vowel, False otherwise'
    for char in s:
        if char.lower() not in 'aeiou':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

No matter the string, it always returns True.

Comment: Well, I bet it will return `False` if you pass in `'a'` as the string...since you're always returning after the first character (and never check any other characters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've almost got it right, but the problem is, as soon as you see a character that is a non-vowel, you return True right then and there. You want to return True after you've made sure that **all** are non-vowel:

```
def noVowel(s):
    'return True if string s contains no vowel, False otherwise'
    for char in s:
        if char.lower() in 'aeiou':
            return False
    return True  # We didn't return False yet, so it must be all non-vowel.
```

It's important to remember that `return` stops the rest of the function from running, so only return if you're sure the function is done computing. In your case, we can safely `return False` once we see a vowel, even if we didn't check the whole string.

Comment: I literally just tried that after posting haha. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

With `any` and short circuiting properties:

```
def noVowel(s):
    return not any(vowel in s.lower() for vowel in "aeiou")
```